# what is SingletonImmutableBiMap from guava

Tags: java, guava

My question is simple. What is `SingletonImmutableBiMap` from `guava` and why it contains keywords like `singleton` and `bi`?

It's very clear what an `ImmutableMap` means but what is the purpose of the other two keywords?

When shall we use this implementation? I noticed this class by calling

`.stream().collect(ImmutableMap.toImmutableMap(ConfigItem::getId, Function.identity()))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Singleton`: contains just 1 element. For immutable collections, their size doesn't change and so you can have separate implementations for empty, single-element or otherwise small collections. It's useful because they need a lot less memory than general implementations and can perform faster. E.g. for an `EmptyMap` `contains` method can be just `return false` instead of complex hash-table lookup logic.

`Bi`: bidirectional, i.e. you can get key by values as well as value by key. See https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html.

> When shall we use this implementation?

Never, because it isn't public. Its existence is an internal detail.

Answer (score 4):

Actual class used here is an implementation detail and you should not be worried about it.

[`SingletonImmutableBiMap`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/v21.0/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/SingletonImmutableBiMap.java) it's an instance of `ImmutableMap` created when you collect stream containing one element. The map in this case is also a [`BiMap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html), since both all key(s) and value(s) are unique. Guava optimizes total class count by re-using `SingletonImmutableBiMap` for both `Map` and `BiMap` case.

**EDIT:**

BTW You probably can use [`Maps.uniqueIndex`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#uniqueIndex-java.lang.Iterable-com.google.common.base.Function-) here:

```
Map<Integer, ConfigItem> m = Maps.uniqueIndex(configItems, ConfigItem::getId);
```